# Noether nomalization theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

**Noether Normalization theorem**

For finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$, there is a polynomial ring $k[x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_d]$ over which $A$ is finite.

I want to know the specific geometric background of it. It's easy to know that the homomorphism from the polynomial ring to $A$ implies a morphism from a variety whose coordinates ring is $A$ to a linear subspace of some affine space. But where to find the reflection of finite？

Comment: This basically gives you a finite map $X \to \mathbb A^n$. For example, for curve this gives you a finite cover $f : X \to \mathbb A^1$, so you can see $X$ as a ramified covering of $A^1$. 
Example : the parabola $x = y^2$ induce a map of degree two by projecting on $x$, with a ramification point at the origin.

Comment: @N.H. could you tell me on which book I can find this theory in details?

Comment: When you say finite you mean integral, right ? Are you asking for the intuition of a finite map or an integral map ?

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113547/intuition-behind-or-canonical-examples-of-finite-type-morphisms/2114006#2114006 for intuition on finite maps. They are basically covering maps like in Riemann surfaces.