# Finite type morphisms and localizations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

I am trying to get some geometric intuition for finite type and locally finite type morphisms of schemes. I have found similar questions but was not able to understand the answers sufficiently well to feel I have gained any real intuition.

For starters, finite type seems to be a strong form of compactness (i.e of pulling back compacts to compacts).

In [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1643/69037) it is said that "finite type" is about finite dimensional fibers while [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1839/69037) to the same question says "locally finite type" is about "finite dimensionality of small neighborhoods of the source of the map". I don't understand these intuitions at all and would appreciate examples to sharpen the "finite dimensionality of small neighborhoods".

The answers to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2113547/223002) both dwell on localizations and their topological structure, seemingly hinting that localizations provide geometric intuition for finite type morphisms. Unfortunately, I don't understand at all: what is this geometric intuition?

I would especially like to understand the latter example of localization and its relation to finite type since it does not feel as vague as "finite dimensionality of neighborhoods".

Comment: I am not an expert in this. But i try to understand  these properties between affine schemes and what does that property correspond between the map of rings. For me finite type condition between affine schemes is equivalent of saying that the morphism between rings is Integral and thus    you can say that the dimension of the two rings are the same. I don't know whether this helps you or not. I haven't encounter any geometrical meaning of my own.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your question about 'finite dimensionality of small neighbourhoods', recall that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is locally of finite type, then for any affine open $U = \text{spec} A \subseteq Y$, we can cover $f^{-1}(U)$ by open affines $\text{spec} B_i \subset f^{-1}(U)$ such that $B_i$ is a finitely generated $A-$algebra.

So if you fix any $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ (i.e. the source of the map), then if you take some small affine neighbourhood $\text{spec} B_i$ around $x$, then the corresponding morphism $\text{spec} B_i \rightarrow \text{spec} A$ has finite dimensional fibres. This is not the same as saying $f$ has finite dimensional fibres, since you can imagine that your preimage has infinitely many disjoint copies of open affines with increasing dimension.

You are right that there is finite type gives some extra compactness condition, in fact finite type = locally finite type + quasi-compact (Hartshorne exercise 3.3(a)). In this case the problem we had above doesn't happen, since we can cover the preimage by finitely many open affines.

Comment: Dear user37864, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I failed to ask my question clearly enough - what I am struggling with is not the gap between locally and globally finite type, but rather with a precise intuition for finite type. If you could point me to results which precisely characterize finite type morphisms via dimensions, or explain the relevance of localizations, I would infinitely appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if there is a way to characterize finite type morphisms via dimensions. The remark on localisation seems to be saying the map $\text{spec} k[x]_{(x)} \rightarrow \text{spec} k[x]$ is not finite type, since $k[x]_{(x)}$ is not finitely generated as a $k[x]$-module. In fact I think this example rules out the idea that one can characterise finite type morphisms via dimensions. 

I'm not very sure what the post intended to say about localisation & finite type morphisms, apart from making the remark that the local ring is usually not finitely generated.

Comment: In general I'm not sure if there is a way to view finite type morphisms completely geometrically - perhaps one way is to say that affine locally on the source, your fibres are given by the same equations with varying coefficients as you vary your point in the target.

Comment: Dear user37864, could you please elaborate? What you wrote seems very geometric to me and I would like to understand it better.

Comment: What I'm really saying is that if you have a morphism $\text{spec} A \rightarrow \text{spec} B$ which is of finite type, i.e. $A= B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$, then if you consider the fibre over any point, i.e. for any point $x$, take $\text{spec} k(x) \rightarrow spec B$, where $k(x)$ is the residue field of $x$, then the fibre is  $\text{spec}A\otimes_B k = \text{spec}k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$. By same equations I mean they're all coming from the same ideal $I$, and when you compute the tensor product the coefficients of the terms in $I$ (which lie in $B$) are now coefficients which lie in $k$,

Comment: and this depends on which point you're taking the fibre. As a simple example if we consider the morphism $\text{spec} k[x,y,t]/(xy-t) \rightarrow \text{spec} k[t]$, then your fibres over any point $t=a$ would be cut out by $xy-a$ in $\text{spec}k[x,y]$. So maybe one way of visualising finite type morphisms is to remember some example like this. 

It is quite often to view a morphims of schemes $X\rightarrow Y$ as $Y$ parametrising some family of objects given by the fibres of $X$, and this leads to notions such as flatness and smoothness.

Comment: For example, one equivalent definition of a smooth morphism is that the map is flat and its geometric fibres are smooth (regular) (Hartshorne Thm. III.10.1.2).

Comment: Dear user37864, first of all is $k=k(x)$ in the first of your last three comments? Second, why is the finiteness of the number of generators crucial? In the general case we'd be able to present $A$ as a quotient of a free $B$-algebra, perhaps on infinitely many variables, by an ideal $I$. Wouldn't all your other statements carry over analogously? That is, wouldn't the fibers still come from the same ideal $I$? I don't understand the geometric input of finiteness here.

Comment: Actually you are right for both your questions - so I guess the fibres should be finite dimensional, cut by finite number of equations cutting out in $\mathbb{A}^n_{k(x)}$. But in general I'm not sure these conditions, or any fibrewise condition, necessarily imply that the morphism is finite type.